# Signal R taking around 1 minute to connect to Hub in mobile network Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

Below is my code to connect to the hub.
I used the below code for connecting the hub and send a message.

```
public ChatService(){
connection = new HubConnection(Services.ServerConstant.BaseUrl);
proxy = ChatServices._connection.CreateHubProxy("HubName");
}
```

//to start connection

```
Void async Start(){
 var http = new Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Http.DefaultHttpClient();
 await _connection.Start(new WebSocketTransportLayer(http));
}
```

//For Connection

```
Void SendMessage(){
 chatServices = DependencyService.Get<IChatServices>();
 chatServices.Connect();
connection.Start();
  await connection.Send("Test");
}
```

Comment: Based on the code you are showing, its not really possible to detect the issues. Show the whole method.

Comment: Thank you for your time. please check again i updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You are recreating connection to hub every time you send the message. That's wrong approach. Instead you should check connection status and reconnect only in case the connection is lost.

Example

```
private async Task CheckConnection()
{
    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Connected)
    {
        return;
    }
    try
    {
        await connection.Start();
        await proxy.Invoke("Connect");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      // your exception handler goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply.this time its take first-time connection happens. At that time its new connection still its take such time

Comment: Did you check response time directly with serwer and what DependencyService.Get<IChatServices>(); is doing?